# Showing a map from projective space can't be extended

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, affine-varieties, zariski-topology

Let $\ U = \big\{ \ [x:y]\in\mathbb{P}^1 \big|\ x\neq0\big\}$  and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$  be the map

$$f([x:y])=\frac{y}{x}$$

Show this is a morphism $U\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ and that it **can't** be extended to a map $\ \ \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$.

My attempt was was to show $U$ is dense in $\mathbb{P}^1$ and use that to get a contradiction. I also proved $U$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$ but I dont think its much helpful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: A map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^1$ is just an element of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathbb{P}^1)$, do you know what this ring is?

Comment: It is all the regular functions given locally by $\frac{h}{g}$ where $h,g$ are homogeneous

Comment: Yes, but do you know what the ring of global regular maps on a **projective** variety is? If not, you might want to check Hartshorne, Theorem 3.4 in chapter I, part a), or its equivalent in Shafarevich: corollary 1.1 of section 5, chapter I.

Comment: Also, in what you said, $g$ and $h$ should be of the same degree.

Comment: Hartshorne, Theorem 3.4 states that $O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(Y) = k$  for $Y$ a closed set of $\mathbb{P}^1$ but this set is open. How can this help? Looking at the complement?

Comment: The first part states that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathbb{P}^1) = k$. In other words, the only morphisms $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^1$ are the constants. Your map is not constant and thus cannot be extended.